# Trigger submit event created with codeigniter with backbone.js

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, backbone.js

Am learning my first steps on backbone.js..

Building an app in codeigniter, submit button triggers the function in application controller to send the data to the database..

```
<?php echo form_open('welcome/process_form','myform') . "\n"; ?>
<p><label for="value">Value: </label><?php echo form_input('value'); ?></p>
<p><label for="tags">Tags: </label><?php echo form_input('tags'); ?></p>
<?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit'); echo form_close();  ?>
```

As simple as that.. a simple codeigniter form and submit button..

Now i want to include backbone.js in the scenario and want it to perform the action obviously reload..

What features of backbone do i look for and get started..??

Comment: You might want to accept serveral of your old questions...

Comment: what do you mean.. delete unanswered questions??

Comment: got that.. i missed that part somehow.. now can we talk about this question..

Comment: Showing your code could help some more.

Comment: added the code to question itself..

Answer (score 0):

The documentation will probably be the best feature to look for...

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model

Try to get a handle of what you need to do. Check out some of the (many) examples. Try to make something work then come back and ask a question about a specific problem you are having (if any).

Your question here sounds as if you created a form in CI and now want to use backbone.js Perhaps someone here *will* write the app for you, but generally the process works best when it's a team effort. i.e. try it yourself; if you get stuck come back for help with the problem.

Comment: well.. yeah.. it always works like that.. try and come up with the specific problem.. 

I tried being as specific as i could, i am starting to learn backbone.js, and not able to get started, its like full of models, collections, views which none seams working independently, even a hello world is tricky..

Comment: Moreover is it necessary to use the restfull server implementation in codeigniter for utilizing backbone.js features as it increases the overload of codeigniter development

Comment: I suppose it isn't necessary, but why reinvent the wheel? http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/ AND http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html Use that REST implementation and the example todo. Get that working and I'll bet you'll be in great shape to get your app going.

Comment: i found them a bit tough to pick up.. there is no sample app for getting started that is built on backbone in combination with codeigniter as well as its restfull server implementation.. so something like that will be helpful for any beginner.. if you are aware of all of them, please do an app if possible a tutorial with all of them

Comment: i found a great example ..https://github.com/melvynhills/backbone-ci.. but even after importing the given sql file, this doesn't work.. can you help